# Vue v2, Nested routes while using a microfrontend architecture using Webpack 5 Module Federation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, micro-frontend, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I was wondering what would be the best way to import routes from [app_02](https://github.com/lisiyizu/webpack5-module-federation-for-vue/blob/93c8572439d4e164e22a857fb0318cc49d0c9838/packages/app-02/src/router/index.js) to [app_01](https://github.com/lisiyizu/webpack5-module-federation-for-vue/blob/93c8572439d4e164e22a857fb0318cc49d0c9838/packages/app-01/src/router/index.js) which is the shell app. One way could be adding children routes but I was wondering if there would be another way to do that so that we can do that so that we don't have to import the components again into the shell app. The main aim of this would be to be able to import different packages having their internal routes into the shell from a config that's in a database.